# How to check if a child in firebase database exists using Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

the following code throws attribute error

> ''Database' object has no attribute 'exists''.

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views import View
    from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
    import pyrebase
    from django.contrib import auth
    import json
    import requests
    from . import services
    from .models import Product


    authe = services.firebase_key().auth()
    database = services.firebase_key().database()

    def Login(request):

        return render(request, "Login.html")


    def postsign(request):

         data = services.get_products()
         print(data)

         context = {'data': data}
         number = request.POST.get('number')
         password = request.POST.get("password")




         if database.child("users").child(number).exists():
             user = database.child("users").child(number).get().val()
             if user['number'] == number:
               if user['password'] == password:

                 return render(request,"Welcome.html",context)
```

I need to check if the number exists in the database or not since I want the existing users to log in using numbers and passwords.

Comment: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

Check if child exist in Python using [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase), should be something similar, see official docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db)

```
if not database.child('users').shallow().get().val():
    print("users does not exist")
else:
    print("users exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.

```
if database.child('users').child(number).shallow().get().val():
    print("user exists")
else:
    print("user does not exist")
```